# Update recycler view in fragment from activity

Tags: android

I have a `FloatingActionButton` and `RecyclerView` in one of my `fragments`. `Fab` opens a new activity where user can save a task into `sqlite` and all the saved tasks from `sqlite` are shown in the recycler view. Now what I want is that when the user saves a new task and click on the back button of the activity from `toolbar`, the recycler view should be updated automatically. Right now, I have to switch to another `fragment` and then come back to the previous one to see the newly created task. I researched about it and found that `interfaces` are the best option for this but I am having problems passing the `context` of the `fragment` to the `activity`.

Here is the `activity` for new task creation:

```
public class AddTaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DataUpdateListener dataUpdateListener;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_task);

        dataUpdateListener = (CalendarFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_calendar);


        ActionBar supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (supportActionBar != null) {
            supportActionBar.setTitle(R.string.add_task);
            supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

    }

    private void saveTask(String task_type, String task) {
// this method is used to save the task in sqlite
        byte[] imageByteArray;
        if (addPictureBtn.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            imageByteArray = Utils.getImageByteArray(selectedImage);
            if (Utils.saveTask(task_type, imageByteArray, task, 0) != -1) {
                AlertDialog alertDialog = Utils.showProgressDialog(this, R.layout.success_popup);
                Button okBtn = (Button) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.okBtn);
                okBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                });
            } 
            dataUpdateListener.onDataUpdate();

        }     
    }

public interface DataUpdateListener {
        void onDataUpdate();
    }
    
}
```

This is my `fragment` which is implementing the `interface`:

```
public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment implements AddTaskActivity.DataUpdateListener {

    CalendarView calendarView;
        TextView noTaskFoundTV;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        FloatingActionButton addTaskBtn;
    
        private FragmentCalendarBinding binding;
        CalendarTasksAdapter calendarTasksAdapter;
    
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                                 ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            binding = FragmentCalendarBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
            return binding.getRoot();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull @NotNull View view, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            calendarView = view.findViewById(R.id.calendar);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            long milliTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
            calendarView.setDate(milliTime, true, true);
    
            recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
            noTaskFoundTV = view.findViewById(R.id.noTaskFound);
    
            addTaskBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
            addTaskBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AddTaskActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            });
    
            fetchTodayPendingTasks();
        }
    
        public void fetchTodayPendingTasks() {
            JSONObject todayTasksFromDB = Utils.getTodayPendingTasksFromDB();
            if (todayTasksFromDB != null) {
                noTaskFoundTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                try {
                    JSONArray tasks = todayTasksFromDB.getJSONArray("tasks");
                    calendarTasksAdapter = new CalendarTasksAdapter(getActivity(), tasks);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(calendarTasksAdapter);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView();
            binding = null;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onDataUpdate() {
//this toast never triggers/shown when the task is created from the activity
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Triggered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

}
```

Comment: what is your question? and can you show the code that you had done?

Comment: My question is "How can I automatically refresh the recycler view in my fragment when the new task is created from another activity?"

Comment: add your realization

Comment: The best way is liveData if your fragment with the recyclerview observe the livedata, he will see the change then your list will be updated

Comment: Yes, you should use livedata, please study how to get livedata object from sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Please try to open activity through startActivityResult like

**In fragment**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AddTaskActivity.class); startActivityForResult(intent,requestcode);
```

**In addtaskactivity**

```
Intent inten =new Intent()
setResult with OK
```

and then again check onActivityResult in fragment with request code, you can refresh you view here

Or another way to check and refresh in onStart() method of fragment with one static Boolean variable updated from task activity and again false this Boolean from onstart when you finish refreshing. But first of all I would prefer first way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onResumed` method of fragment lifecycle.
you should override `onResumed` Method on `CalendarFragment`
This method is called after returning to the main page.
call `fetchTodayPendingTasks();` in onResumed method.

It is better to make changes in the `fetchTodayPendingTasks`. like this:

```
public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment implements AddTaskActivity.DataUpdateListener {

    CalendarView calendarView;
        TextView noTaskFoundTV;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        FloatingActionButton addTaskBtn;
    
        private FragmentCalendarBinding binding;
        CalendarTasksAdapter calendarTasksAdapter;
    
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                                 ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            binding = FragmentCalendarBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
            return binding.getRoot();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull @NotNull View view, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            calendarView = view.findViewById(R.id.calendar);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            long milliTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
            calendarView.setDate(milliTime, true, true);
    
            recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
            noTaskFoundTV = view.findViewById(R.id.noTaskFound);
    
            addTaskBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
            addTaskBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AddTaskActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            });
            calendarTasksAdapter = new CalendarTasksAdapter(getActivity());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(calendarTasksAdapter);
            fetchTodayPendingTasks();
        }
    
        public void fetchTodayPendingTasks() {
            JSONObject todayTasksFromDB = Utils.getTodayPendingTasksFromDB();
            if (todayTasksFromDB != null) {
                noTaskFoundTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                try {
                    JSONArray tasks = todayTasksFromDB.getJSONArray("tasks");
                adapter.setData(tasks)
                    
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView();
            binding = null;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onDataUpdate() {
//this toast never triggers/shown when the task is created from the activity
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Triggered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

}
```

and you should define a `setData` method in your adapter. Do not forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

```
public void setData(JSONArray array){
    // set to your data list
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of usage, the best practice is to use Room database which is basically wrapping sqlite with abstraction layer. And then you could use LiveData.

Perfect example with source code can be found [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/main/BasicRxJavaSample).